# Event handler function out of scope in for

Tags: javascript, dom-events, mouseevent, onmouseover

The handler inside of my for loop might be out of scope and only prints "Last Event added" in console but doesn't loop through each element in the array. No sure where I'm going wrong here, but I need help attaching the event listener to each.

```
(function () {
    if (document.addEventListener) {
        this.addEvent = function (elem, type, fn) {
            elem.addEventListener(type, fn, false);
        };
    } else if (document.attachEvent) {
        this.addEvent = function (elem, type, fn) {
            var bound = function () {
                return fn.apply(elem, arguments);
            };
            elem.attachEvent("on" + type, bound);
            return bound;
        };
    }
    if (document.getElementsByClassName) {
        this.getClass = function (className) {
            return document.getElementsByClassName(className);
        };
    } else if (document.querySelectorAll) {
        this.getClass = function (className) {
            return document.querySelectorAll("." + className);
        };
    }
    var elem = getClass("images"),
        display = getClass("display_box"),
        rolloverImage = function (e) {
            console.log("Event 'rolloverImage' triggered");
        };
    console.log(display);
    console.log(elem);
    console.log(elem.length);
    for (var i = 0; i < elem.length; i++) {
        document.addEvent(elem[i], "mouseover", rolloverImage);
        if (i = elem.length) {
            console.log("Last event added");
        } else {
            console.log("Event added to " + elem[i]);
        }
    };
})();
```

A fiddle is available here: http://jsfiddle.net/bNL5C/

Answer (score 1):

if you are wanting your `addEvent` function to be on the document object use `document.addEvent =` not `this.addEvent =` as that is putting it on the global object `window`

Also it doesnt loop through all of them because you are assigning `i` to the `elem` array length instead of comparing.

```
if (i = elem.length) {
```

should be

```
if (i == elem.length) {
```

Because of this on the first iteration through the loop causes `i` to be the value of `elem.length` and since `i` is now not `< elem.length` your loop exits.

Answer (score 1):

One problem is that in your `for` loop, the `if (i = elem.length)` will always be true, as you are using a single assignment `=`, and changing the value of `i`.  This needs to be changed to `if (i == elem.length)` or perhaps you'd prefer to use `===`.